# Square POS API - Possible to get sales info from dashboard

Tags: python, api, square, square-connect, pos

I want to get how many of each item i sold in a set period of time, and be able to export and manipulate the data. Doing a manual download and then excel takes too long.

Basically is it possible to use the API to pull down dashboard information from a certain period of time? Would like net, gross, tip, tax, individual sales info, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Transactions endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions), the `begin_time` and `end_time` will let you window transactions to specific dates.